# Playing real-time sound from serial port (COM)

Tags: naudio, naudio-framework

I'm using arduino's ADC to capture data from external microphone and send it through the serial port. My question is: How to capture and play this data with NAudio?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know how to receive audio from a serial port, you'd put it into a `BufferedWaveProvider` as you received it. The `BufferedWaveProvider` can be played with `WaveOutEvent`